# Find all values of p, such that the roots of $f(x) = x^3 + 8 x^2 + px + 12$ satisfy $x_1 + x_2 = x_3$

Tags: polynomials

Find **all values** of p, such that the roots of $$f(x) = x^3 + 8x^2 + px + 12$$ satisfy $x_1 + x_2 = x_3$

So I was trying to use the Viet formulas, and I get:
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3  = -8$$
$$x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + x_2x_3 = p$$
$$x_1x_2 x_3 = -12$$
$$x_1 + x_2 = x_3$$
But I can't find an easy way to get a formula for p. Any tips?

Comment: Look more closely at the first and last equalities you just wrote.

Comment: I can see that $x_3 = -4$, but how does that help?

Comment: HINT: A root always satisfies the equation.

Comment: @SimonJachson $\;f(-4)=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = -8$ and $x_1 + x_2 = x_3$, then $x_3 = -4$.
Then $$f(-4) = (-4)^3 + 8 (-4)^2 + p*(-4) + 12 =  76 - 4p = 0 $$
Then $p = 19$.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other answer, if you want to use Vieta's formulas, you can see that $x_1x_2=\frac{-12}{-4}=3$. Using this in $x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + x_2x_3 = p$, we get $$x_1x_2 + (x_1 + x_2)x_3 = p\\\implies x_1x_2 + x_3^2 = p\\\implies 3+16=p$$

So, the answer is $p=19$.

Answer (score 0):

We know $x_1+x_2+x_3=-8$ and $x_1+x_2=x_3$. Thus we get $x_3=-4$.

$$ f(x)=x^3+8x^2+px+12=0 $$

Put $x$ as $-4$ and find the value of $p$